# Multiple Inheritance in C# with Calling to base methods

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

```
using System;               


public class A
{
    public  virtual string GetDataFromA()
    {
       return "This Is base Class A" ;  
    }
}

public class B
{
    public  virtual string GetDataFromB()
    {
       return "This Is base Class B" ;  
    }
}

public class C : B,A
{
     public overide string GetDataFromB()
     {
         var data = base.GetDataFromB();
         return data + "This Is child Class C";
     }

     public overide string GetDataFromA()
     {
         var data = base.GetDataFromB();
         return data + "This Is child Class C";
     }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myCobject = new c();
        c.GetDataFromB();
        c.GetDataFromA();
    }
}
```

This is a simple Question and i know we cant use multiple inheritance in C# that is the reason we use interface .But My problem is how i call base class method when i am using multiple Inheritance 
 please let me know if i missing Something .I want to call both A and B base class method in my Class C .**In the mean time i want to call to base class method in child class method Both A and B**

Comment: C# does not support multiple inheritance by design.  The closest you will get is interfaces with default method implementations.

Comment: Yes I understand, that is why i put  message we use interface .But the main problem is that i have use virtual methods in two deference class and override both methods and call to the base method  how do we implement this type of a problem

Comment: "i know we cant use multiple inheritance in C# ... My problem is how i ____ when i am using multiple Inheritance" Ummmm... you don't? I really don't get how someone could ask a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at "composition over inheritance" idea, you may solve your issue by below code. The reason why we choose composition can be explained in this link (https://medium.com/humans-create-software/composition-over-inheritance-cb6f88070205). There are still some other ways to solve this, one of that is decorator pattern. But to keep it simple, composition is good enough to do the job.

```
public class A
{
    public  virtual string GetDataFromA()
    {
       return "This Is base Class A" ;  
    }
}

public class B
{
    public  virtual string GetDataFromB()
    {
       return "This Is base Class B" ;  
    }
}

public class C
{
     private readonly _aService = new A();
     private readonly _bService = new B();
     public overide string GetDataFromB()
     {
         var data = _bService.GetDataFromB();
         return data + "This Is child Class C";
     }

     public overide string GetDataFromA()
     {
         var data = _aService.GetDataFromB();
         return data + "This Is child Class C";
     }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myCobject = new c();
        c.GetDataFromB();
        c.GetDataFromA();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the basic of  OOP concept :), there is concept which is still i am searching that you can inherit multiple interface and talk to every and each base class .its call interface as a maker but i cant find a good blog or any information about it .  this is fine :) but its just creating object in inside a class and you cant do this when its come to dependency injection ..

Answer (score 0):

It has risk of getting messy. Easy solution to this is class composition, as below:

```
public class A
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data coming from A");
    }
}
// Here we use composition over inheritance.
public class B
{
    A _a;
    public B()
    {
      _a = new A();
    }
    public virtual void GetData()
    {
        _a.GetData();
        Console.WriteLine("Data coming from B");
    }
}
public class C : B 
{
    public override void GetData()
    {
        base.GetData();
        Console.WriteLine("Data coming from C");
    }
}
```

Now, used like this, you can use below code:

```
var c = new C();
c.GetData();
```

which produces output:

```
Data coming from A
Data coming from B
Data coming from C
```

**Further note**: you can easily apply composition to `B` and `C` classes as well, in the same way I did for `A` and `B`.

Comment: This way also Good but this is  the constructor chain not the way of  multiple inheritance  with Interface. there is concept which is still i am searching that you can inherit multiple interface and talk to every and each base class .its call interface as a maker but i cant find a good blog or any information about it  :) .